# Asp.net 5 Class library (Package) cant find System.xml

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Im trying to create "Class Library (pacakge)" for new Asp.net 5 rc1 webapi.

before using of asp.net 5 the usage of class library was simple and I just add

the referenced dll or Class library project to my Main webapi Solution.

now when i want to add normal Class library to asp.net 5 project it gave me error.

so im going to convert all my normal library into new "Class library (package)".

the problem is after i copied my CS class it couldnt detect the normal dll

like xml even after i add them into Project.json Like this:

error :

[image]

and the project.json structure :

[image]

what should i do ? is there any chance that new asp.net 5 structure accept

old class library DLL ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add "System.Xml" and "System.Xml.XmlSerializer" in the net451 section, like that :

```
"frameworks": {
    "net451": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    },
    "dotnet5.4": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Collections": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Linq": "4.0.1-beta-23516",
        "System.Runtime": "4.0.21-beta-23516",
        "System.Threading": "4.0.11-beta-23516",
        "System.Xml.XmlDocument": "4.0.1-beta-23224",
        "System.Xml.XmlSerializer": "4.0.11-beta-23224"
      }
    }
```